# Cannot convert value of type when trying to get latitude and longitude from text fields

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

[Image of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MyLR.png)

My code isn't working.
When the user puts in a latitude and longitude it's supposed to go to Maps but it just throws an error. It only works when I hard-code the latitude and longitude.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Longitude: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Latitude_button: UITextField!

    @IBAction func showMeWhere(_ sender: Any)
    {
        //Defining destination
        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = Latitude_button
        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = Longitude

      //        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = 39.048825
    //        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = -120.981227

        let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 1000;
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)

        let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center), MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)]

        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = "Test Location"
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to assign a `UITextField` variable to a variable of type `CLLocationDegrees`?

Comment: You can't assign a UITextField as a CLLocationDegrees. Try getting the text of the textFields and cast that as a double and assign that value to latitude or longitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your line `let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = Latitude_button` you are attempting to assign a variable of type `UITextField` to a variable of type `CLLocationDegrees`.

What you need to do is get the text from the text field and attempt to convert it into a number and then assign that number to your variable.

```
guard let latitude = CLLocationDegrees(Latitude_button.text!),
      let longitude = CLLocationDegrees(Longitude.text!) else {
    // show some sort message to the user that the values are invalid
    return
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The type isn't correct.

Change 
`let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = Latitude_button` 
to 
`Double(Latitude_button.text ?? "") ?? 0`.

Same to `longitude`

`let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = Double(Longitude.text ?? "") ?? 0`

Also, your name conventions isn's very proper. Should be like `latitudeButton` and `longitude`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things that might help you getting started, as I've been there:

1. In Swift, variables are in `camelCase`, and, by convention, stay away from `snake_case` and `Capitalized` for variable declarations. I would do something like this for your `@IBOutlets`...

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var longitudeField: UITextField!
   @IBOutlet weak var latitudeField: UITextField!
   ```
2. `UITextFields` have `Strings` in them, but inside your `showMeWhere` method, you're trying to pull assign a `UITextField` to a `CLLocationDegrees`.

   - [`UITextField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield) has a property called `text`. That's what you want, not the field...you want the text IN the field.
   - [`CLLocationDegrees`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationdegrees#) is a `typealias` for a `Double`...so the issue before you is converting a `String` to a `Double`.

Here's how you'd do it:

```
guard let latitude = Double(latitudeField.text), 
      let longitude = Double(longitudeField.text) else { return }
```